# Who defines `defer` in `deploy.rb`?

Tags: ruby, capistrano, whenever, whenever-capistrano

In `whenever`'s README, there is an example like this,

```
set :whenever_environment, defer { stage }
require "whenever/capistrano"
```

I probably understand what `defer` means, but I want to know how it works, and how it is implemented.

Where can I find the source code of `defer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defer` used to be part of the [capistrano v2 gem](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/v2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration.rb#L33-L34). It is nothing more than an alias to the ruby `lambda` and is used only for readability purposes.

As you might know in capistrano you can `set` many variables. Their values are calculated upon initialization of the capistrano script [unless a value is a block](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/v2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb#L72-L92). In that context `defer` makes more sense as a keyword since evaluation is defered until the variable is accessed.